# Publish Azure Mobile Apps Backend

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-plans

When going to publish my Mobile Service Backend there is supposed to be an option that says "Microsoft Azure App Service" but instead I get two other options: "Microsoft Azure Web Apps" & "Microsoft Azure API Apps (Preview)".

The Web Apps option identifies my service plan and SQL server but wants me to create a new mobile web app url which I already have.

Neither of these show my App Service I have already created. Is it because I don't have Azure SDK v2.9 or higher (as stated by the online resource I'm using)? When going into the NuGet Packages and it only has v2.0 for Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Server and no higher version

Anybody know how to get the higher SDK without going through VS 2015 or any other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly check the existing of the mobile service resource in the VS2015 server explorer.

You could open it in the view --> server explorer.

[image]

> Anybody know how to get the higher SDK without going through VS 2015 or any other options?

If this resource is existing, but the publish windows doesn't show this resource.

I suggest you could update your azure SDK(the newest is 3.0.1), you could install it in this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/).

[image]

Besides, I suggest you could check you have created mobile service not web app service.

Comment: Turns out in the Azure Portal there is an option in the top right corner that says 'Get publish file'. This creates a document on your computer that you can import when publishing in VS 2015.